# Reply message logic (Imap)

Tags: php, smtp, imap

I have a problem I do a project in the management of email.

Idea: List the emails. When entering an email, list all the answers to e-mail.

Problem: To find out if an email is another e-mail response'm using the "references" that comes from "imap_headerinfo" function.
This works in many cases. The big problem is when the field "message_id" is empty. This causes the next value of the "references" field is:

"xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx" "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx" "" "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx" "xxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xx"

It returns in the middle of a blank space. Thus I can not know the e-mail that belongs there.

There is another way to know that the email is that response from another e-mail?

Comment: Why doesn't the message have a Message_ID header?  This is required by SMTP specifications.  If you don't have it, the message is broken, and it should not be a big deal if it's missing from the conversation.

Comment: I do not know why has not the id. The e ta correct and you can read well :/